# Flutter Draggable: When drag on started, how to stop the draggable gesture(make the finger's draggable Widget disappear)?

Tags: flutter, draggable

Flutter Draggable: When drag on started, how to stop the draggable gesture(make the finger's draggable Widget disappear)? When tap on the other page, I must stop the draggable.